# What is the right storage of a html file in a mongodb

Tags: html, database, mongodb, nosql

If I have understood this correctly, one advantage of a document-oriented database like MongoDB is that unstructured data can be stored well. For example, If I have different HTML files, is the complete storage in a string in each document an advantage ? Or is it so thought that the different single contents of the HTML files are stored separately as many key-value pairs and only then make a HTML file out of it ?

Answer (score 0):

If its a matter of storing the HTML content only, you can directly save it as a string. Text searching can also be done easily by going this route.

On the other side, if you need to process different elements, dynamically assign some values, replace some placeholders, etc. then you can think of saving associated tags/elements separately.